Player activity destroyed when paused - How to reproduce?
My app uses ExoPlayer to play audio. It has a PlayerActivity which has play/pause buttons. This activity is usually in the background as the user continues to listen to audio via a foreground service.
Some of my users are reporting that when the PlayerActivity is paused and in background, after some time they bring it back up to the foreground, the activity has been destroyed by the system. For example, the seekbar is at 0 and the mp3 file shows a length of 0.
So I suspect that some sort of Energy setting kills the activity. I am trying to reproduce this error on the emulator but I cannot succeed.
What I have tried:

I have activated "Don't keep activities" in DevOptions
I have set the background processes to "No background processes" in DevOptions



I have also set the battery status to 1% hoping that the "killing" energy mode will kick in.


So I play an audio, click "Pause", place the activity in the background, open some random apps, bring it back up, but the PlayerActvity just looks fine. Everything is there as it should be.
Do you guys have any idea how I can reproduce the error my users are getting?? I am really clueless on this one. Thanks for your help.

It could be a device/manufacturer specific issue, that we see all too often

So how to tackle?? These users have Samsung Galaxy devices.

You could try persisting the data somewhere but there probably isnt a good way to fix it since its device/manufacturer specific

thats very easy - just swipe out your Activity from recents. your service should stay untouched and should still play audio, as you are removing only GUI part of your application
and remember that system can manage your Activity as it like, theoretically it can be removed from foreground during user interaction anytime (in very, very stressful case). when your Activity get "homed" you can't be sure it will stay same if you run/bring it back again, even after 3 secs
solution is to handle savedInstanceState at first and then you have to implement some kind of communication between background (service) and foreground (activity) - when Activity starts from scratch (for any reason you can't control) and smth is working in background it should send its state (in your case e.g. playing state, seek position) to Activity

Well, of course I have implemented savedInstanceState properly in that activity. That's why even with the setting "Don't keep activities", the activity works totally fine when bringing it back from background.

saving instance works when Activity gets just homed and isn't destroyed by OS. and some very basic way of Service <-> Activity communication can be found in HERE (bounding Services doc), but nowadays there are plenty of better solutions, faster with less code - this will be useful when Activity gets destroyed in background by OS and starts from scratch, meanwhile Service is alive

That's not my problem. The user has PAUSED the audio, then he homes PlayerActivity. After a long time brings it back up and Activity is killed. That does NOT happen when player is playing. Nothing gets killed in that case.

when audio is playing then system knows that app is running, consuming energy, reources etc. so it may evaluate app as active and preserve Activity alive (probably some other compnent gets killed then). and when player is paused then both Activity and Service are consuming very little, so system is evaluating this app as "homed". I can bet that OS can kill your Activity even when audio is playing and Activity is on foreground - very, very, very rare case. When Activity is in background, but audio is playing - thats a very, very rare case.

And when Activity is in background and audio is paused then its just single-very rare case, which will be reported if you have bigger amount of users (hard to reproduce by single dev). When you would have 1 million of users then sooner or later you may get report that Activity didn't get back properly even when Service was playing continously. Killing alive on screen Activity is probably case when device already decided to switch off, screen may be already blurred showing only "turning off" text, so this probably won't be reported by user

Ok, I understand that. But how come I cannot set up a test environment to reproduce such a system kill?

that question I can't answer, I don't know :) would be glad to get to know some flag or adb command for manipulating stressful states for device/emulator or at least apps sandbox. if you find any working solution (besides these from question) please post
